# UK visa for German resident

Tags: uk, germany, tourist-visas, russian-citizens

Do I need a visa to visit UK as a tourist if I live in Germany with temporary residence permit (Blue Card)? I'm a non-EU citizen.

Comment: Visa-free entry is based on *citizenship*, not residence. You can check if you need a visa here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Russian citizens usually need a visa to come to the UK. Eligibility is based on *citizenship*, not place of residence.

In most cases, you must apply for a Standard Visitor visa. You may be able to apply to enter the UK for free instead of paying for a visa if your partner or family member is a British citizen or from another European country.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y